# Using JOOQ formatJSON to get column:value pairs

Tags: java, jooq

I'd like my *formatJSON()* result to be *column:value* pairs.

> [{"ID":1,"AUTHOR_ID":1,"TITLE":"1984"},{"ID":2,"AUTHOR_ID":1,"TITLE":"Animal Farm"}]

This blog post (https://blog.jooq.org/2018/01/) suggests the result is possible by setting a formatting option flag somewhere, but I am unable to find how to specify that option.   I am just getting the default (?) output:

> {"fields":[{"schema":"sss","table":"ttt","name":"ccc1","type":"zzz"},{"schema":"sss","table":"ttt","name":"ccc2","type":"zzz"}],"records":[[1,"x"]]}

I am using jOOQ 3.7.0, but can upgrade if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am using jOOQ 3.7.0, but can upgrade if needed.

There's your answer. Upgrade to 3.9 or more to profit from [#5372](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5372). You can then call [`Formattable.formatJSON(JSONFormat)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Formattable.html#formatJSON-org.jooq.JSONFormat-) like this:

```java
String json = result.formatJSON(new JSONFormat()
    .header(false)
    .recordFormat(RecordFormat.OBJECT));
```